Run multiple .bat files in all subfolders
I have 932 folders, each containing an album in mp3 format. I have a batch file named Makeplaylist.bat that creates a playlist file from the files and then deletes itself. It runs perfectly
if I run each one manually. But I would like to run them all at once. If I do a search for Makeplaylist.bat and select all results, then press enter, it opens 932 command prompt windows, but doesn't actually run the commands.
Here is the directory structure:
...\Main Folder
       \Album 1
           \01 File 1.mp3
           \02 File 2.mp3
           \03 File 3.mp3
           \04 File 4.mp3
           \Makeplaylist.bat
        
       \Album 2
           \01 File 1.mp3
           \02 File 2.mp3
           \03 File 3.mp3
           \04 File 4.mp3
           \Makeplaylist.bat

    ...\Album ...


write one batch file to execute all the others. they won't all run at once (you won't be able to do that on the scale you describe), but then you only need to run one thing to kick the process off.

Can you please elaborate?  If I knew how to write a batch file to do that, I would have done it already.

@echo off

cd /d "D:\iPod"

for /f delims^= %%G in =;('
     2^>nul "%Windir%\System32\Where.exe" /r "%cd%" "*play*st.bat"
   ');= do cd /d "%%~dpG" && echo/Running: "%%~fG" & call "%%~nxG" 


Save it as SomeName.cmd in the root folder where you have the subfolders with MP3s and .bats.
Call it as you wish, via shortcut, direct click, or command line if preferred.
It will locate and execute each of your .bat files one by one in the same window, recursively.

Note: I believe what you need is a single batch file that can recursively perform what the other batch files do, without the need to call them one by one... use a single batch file to "update" your playlists:
@echo off

cd /d "D:\iPod"

for /r /d  %%G in =;( * );= do =;(
     >nul 2>&1 dir /on /a:-d /b "%%~dpnxG\*.mp3" "%%~dpnxG\*.ogg" && 2>nul =;(
     cd /d "%%~dpnxG" && >"PlayList.m3u" dir /a:-d /on /b .\*.mp3 .\*.ogg );= 
    );=



The first one just lists rows of "File Not Found" and then closes the command prompt.
The second just says "The directory name is invalid"

The first one had an adjustment, while the second one had a pair of adjustments. d;) It was done and tested... Thank you for testing and providing feedback... See if the final edits meet your needs.

It is important that the batch file is located in D:\Full\Path\To\Main\Folder, not in the albums folder. Alternatively, if the batch file is saved there, you can keep cd /d "%~dp0" with the path pointing to that folder.

"File Not Found" will reflect those folders that do not contain any .mp3 or .ogg files, or even neither of them. For these cases, 2>nul was added.

Ok, your latest edit worked.  It did create the playlists, but it names them as the foldernamePlaylist, which I can live with.  My hopes would be that they would all just be named "playlist.m3u".  Is it easy enough to change that?  Absolutely almost there.

Thank you for testing, commenting, and other actions!

You don't need a batch file for that, this looks very simple. Just run this command in the command line (prompt):
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /s "d:\iPod\*Playlist.bat"') do start "" /w /d "%~dpa" "%~nxa"


Yes.  Running each individually works perfectly.  I'm just hoping to not have to run 932 of them.
@echo off
cd %1
echo %~f1
dir /on/b *.mp3 *.ogg > %~n1Playlist.m3u
del MakePlaylist.bat
exit

The playlist.bat files seem to expect to be executed form the same path they are in, I updated the answer see if it works now but try copy files first.

It returns...
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpa"&start /wait "" "%~nxa"
For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
D:\iPod>for /f "tokens=*" \iPod*MakePlaylist.bat"') do CD "aylist.bat"') do CD "%~dpa"&start /wait "" "%~nxa"

Ok try now I updated the answer...

The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpa"&start /wait "" "%~nxa"
For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
